# Use service worker so that it fetches the latest version if internet available and uses last known version if no internet

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

So, normally the service worker works like this:

1. Go to website
2. Load the last known version
3. Check for the latest version while the app is being used
4. Load the new version when all instances of app is closed

Instead, I want it to work like this:

1. When app is being loaded, check if internet is availble.
2. If internet is available fetch and use the latest version
3. If no internet available, use the version that was cached/stored.

Can anyone help me with how to go about doing that?
Thanks
P.S.: I'm using React

Comment: Basically I just don't want the browser to check it's cache at all, if possible. It should just fetch the website from the internet as if it wasn't cached. But, if there is no internet, then it should fetch the website from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need this fetch handler:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
      return caches.match(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

You respond with a fetch. If that fetch fails because there is no network connection you land into the `.catch()` statement and there you load the cached version

I would suggest to use stale while revalidate

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {
          cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
          return networkResponse;
        })
        return response || fetchPromise;
      })
    })
  );
});
```

If you make a request you load the response out of the cache. In the background you make a request to the network and save that response into the cache. If you refresh the page you see now the response from last time.

Here is a good article about PWAs

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook#stale-while-revalidate

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
But this means that it loads the website first, then it checks for a new version. I don't want the website to load at all. It just feels like a bad user experience if the website loaded and then I fetch the new one and load it again.

Comment: this fetch handler loads the website over the network as usual. if there is no network available it loads it from the cache. its the behaviour you want?

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks. That was exactly what I wanted. I'll check if it works and then mark the answer as solved. Thank you.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal but thats not the full answer i guess, you also want to add the request to the cache whenever you load it over the network

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what that means. Can you help me further with an example, or a link where I can read about it? Thanks.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal i updated my answer. there is a good articel from google

Comment: This stale while revalidate looks exactly like the thing I don't want. It says: If there's a cached version available, use it, but fetch an update for next time. But I don't want to use the cached version if I have internet. I only want to use it there's no internet available.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal this is the first approach https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook#network-falling-back-to-cache

Comment: I wrote this code in public/service-worker.js. But for some reason it doesn't work. I even removed the code where I am fetching from cache, so that it doesn't work offline at all. But it still works there. This is a React specific question, but do you know what can be done about this?
Thanks